# Keeping a php variable that is retrieved via _GET when page reloads

Tags: php, sql

I have a page that is the result of a php query click (individual job list). I want to use an `ORDER BY` so the individuals can order their results based on either due date, job name, etc.

The problem seems to come into play when the user clicks on the variable table header. This causes a page refresh and the variable from the `_GET` is obviously then gone. I tried setting it as a cookie but I believe perhaps I am not setting this correctly.

This is in the top of the document:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['assignee'] ) ){
    $assignee = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'assignee', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
}
    $assignee_name = $assignee;
    setcookie($assignee_name, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

This is the `PHP` directly before the `foreach` loop:

```
<?php
     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "jobs_usr1";
     $password = "xxxxxxxxx";
     $dbname = "jobs_users";

     // Create connection
     $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
     // Check connection
     if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jobs_canjobs` WHERE assignee = \"$assignee\"";

    $orderBy = array('job_numb', 'job_name', 'due_date', 'show_date', 'status');

     $order = 'type';
            if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
            $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
        }
                if(isset($_COOKIE[$assignee_name])){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `jobs_canjobs` WHERE assignee = \"$assignee_name\" ORDER BY $order";
                }
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
```

Then in the results table, under the table heads, I have this:

```
<table>
    <tr style="background-color: cadetblue">
        <th><a href="?orderBy=job_numb"><b>Job ID#</b></a></th>
        <th><a href="?orderBy=job_name"><b>Title</b></a></th>
        <th><a href="?orderBy=due_date"><b>Due Date</b></a> | <a href="?orderBy=show_date"><b>Show Date</b></a></th>
        <th><a href="?orderBy=status"><b>Status</b></a></th>
    </tr>
<?php
 foreach ($results as $result){
    $job_numb = $result['job_numb'];
    $assignee = $result['assignee'];
    $job_name = $result['job_name'];
    $due_date = $result['due_date'];
    $show_date = $result['show_date'];
    $status = $result['status'];
?>
<tr>
    <td>
       <p><?php echo $job_numb;?></p>
    </td>
    <td>
       <p><?php echo $job_name;?></p>
    </td>
    <td>
       <p><?php echo $due_date;?> | <?php echo $show_date;?></p>
    </td>
    <td>
       <p><?php echo $status;?></p>
    </td>
</tr>
<? php } ?>
</table>
```

Without the reordering `$order`, it works just fine - but once someone clicks on the `th` with the order by, the variable disappears, and I am not sure how to keep it even after a page reload.

Is there a way to keep this variable `$assignee`on the page so I can reference it again to display the results? I know it is the page refresh because the url after clicking does not contain the variable.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Cookie or session.

Comment: I am trying to use a cookie, but I do not think I implemented it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cool thing about PHP is you can just plonk it just about anywhere within HTML document

```
   <th><a href="?orderBy=job_numb<?php if ( (isset($_GET['assignee'])) && (!empty($_GET['assignee'])) ){
   echo '&assignee='.URL_ENCODE($_GET['assignee']);}?>"><b>Job ID#</b></a></th>
```

This first checks if that var is defined, and isn't defined as ''  aka empty
then appending to your hard coded URL..

Putting that all on one line to ensure no line breaks are introduced to the URL.

So the resulting link will end with &assignee=$VAR  where $VAR is the previously set $_GET['assignee']

PS while working on scripts I always add this to teh top so I can see errors without looking at log files

```
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
error_reporting(-1);
```

Comment: oddly all that did was the entire page had no result. Should I remove it from the head as well?

Comment: What do the URLs look like where you have entered the code snippet I provided? (right click a link and copy link location in most browsers)

Comment: This is the url: `http://someplace.com/job_list_individual.php?assignee=Sean%20Rawles&orderBy=show_date`

Comment: uh..  without my code your URL should look like ?orderBy=job_numb      
I really don't care what domain you have it on.. :D

With my code, you should see it's changed to  ?orderBy=job_numb&assignee=TERM  where TERM is the previously provided $_GET['assignee']


tryin to help.. help me help you :D

Comment: OK  YAY it works... You just need to URL_DECODE $assignee  before using it in your query

    $assignee = URL_DECODE($assignee);

Comment: I know YOU don't care. Regardless, when I add that code, then go to the referring page the entire page is blank and there is no error shown :(

Comment: OH in the top part?

Comment: then there is an error in teh code and yoru server is not set to display errors, although they should be logged somwehere..

You can add this to the top while developing so that errors are displayed, once all is well, comment it out
(MOVED THAT CODE TO MY ANSWER AS a PS since comments dont have code formatting)

Pretty sure my code is syntactically correct.. so.. um  what error do you see ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: assignee_name in /home/jobs/public_html/job_list_individual.php on line 118

Comment: if ( (!isset($_GET['asignee']) || empty($_GET['asignee'])) {
      // no term provided.. not sure what to do
} else {

 $assignee_name = $assignee; 
}